# Transparent regions of pasted png display as black in Inkscape

Tags: opera, chromium, png, inkscape, transparency

If I copy and paste, for instance, [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Wikidata-logo-en.svg/250px-Wikidata-logo-en.svg.png) from Chromium or Opera webbrowsers into Inkscape, the regions which should be transparent are rendered as black, like so:

[image: Wikidata logo in Inkscape]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: The problem does not appear when saving the png to disk and then importing via File -> Import. Maybe my web browser (Chromium) isn't copying the alpha values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie with Inkscape but with the software you copy from.

Under Debian Linux, this image will copy with the correct alpha-value from Iceweasel, but not from Opera web-browser.